# Serverless keeps returning this error libpq.so.5: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Tags: python, aws-lambda, serverless, serverless-framework

I am trying to install dependencies for my lambda functions. I am using the serverless framework and I have specified the necessary configurations.
Note: I am using a dockerfile.

The error I am getting is a postgres related error.

I am trying to connect to a remote postgresDB and I am seeing this error in my logs.

```
libpq.so.5: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

This is my Dockerfile

```
FROM python:3.9

RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get instal libpq-dev -y && apt-get install libpq5 -y

COPY requirements.txt .

RUN pip install --no-cache-dir -r requirements.txt
```

Any form of help will be appreciated.

Comment: Would you be able to share full error output? When do you get this error? When invoking function? During deployment?

Comment: sure, i can do that

Comment: @Somto so many months later have you found any solution?